# A phenomenon in which the cycle of a function is delayed when an error occurs in multiple infinite loop functions executed with python asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

like the following code, I put several infinite loop asynchronous functions in one loop and run them.

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.gather(
                    get_exchange_rate(),
                    data_input(),
                    return_exceptions=True,
                )
    )
finally:
    loop.close()
```

The function to save data should be executed every 5 seconds, but if an error occurs in the function that crawls the exchange rate, it will be delayed during the error time.

The error that occurs is an SSL error as follows, and get_exchange_rate() is a crawl function with a cycle of 30 seconds through BeautifulSoup.

`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='URL', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:`

Comment: `host='URL'` does not look like a valid URL, which is why requests is failing to connect to it, even after multiple retries.

Comment: Edited on purpose. :) Originally, it is an exchange rate URL that is accessible.

Comment: It works fine, but once get_exchange_rate() encounters an error, the rest of the coroutine's cycle is delayed while processing the error. It looks like waiting.

Comment: Try to use async lib such as `aiohttp`, not synchronous `requests`.

Comment: I am afraid this is not really answersable as it is now. Where are the schedulings for 5s, 30s??  Where is the code that actually makes the I/O request?